# Handling Postgres output function parameters in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a Postgres database I wish to access. I need to call several functions that exist in the DB. I have achieved connection to the database and running queries. I have also achieved to call the functions I want. My problem is that when a Postgres function has more than one OUT parameters, instead of returning an array I can access either with the offset or with the row name, it instead returns a string with both the OUT parameters:

```
$query = "Select pg_function('" . Getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") . "')";
$result = pg_query($query);
$line = pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC);
var_dump($line);
```

What var_dumb returns is this:

```
array
    'ua_bl_session_request' => string '(c6787f5f2b2c885168162c8c8ffff220,8fe04393-c188-0e08-b710-a2ce89066768)' (length=71)
```

I can of course parse that string but is there a way to achieve what I want and I am missing it?

Comment: `var_dumb` :-) I like that alias to be incorporated in core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM pg_function(REMOTE_ADDR);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using [pg_fetch_array()](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php) incorrectly, because you should give the row number in the second parameter. For example:

```
// To get the first row (Rows are numbered from 0 upwards)
$line = pg_fetch_array($result, 0, PGSQL_ASSOC);

// To get the second row
$line = pg_fetch_array($result, 1, PGSQL_ASSOC);
```

But if you know what you are doing, you can use [regexp_split_to_table()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-string.html), it is a Posgtres string function that split a string to rows using a POSIX regular expression as the delimiter. For example:

```
$query  = "select regexp_split_to_table(
               pg_function('" . Getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") . "'), ','
           )";
```

In your case, it will split the function's result using `','` as delimiter. It should return a result set with two rows, like below:

```
c6787f5f2b2c885168162c8c8ffff220
8fe04393-c188-0e08-b710-a2ce89066768
```